# The Difference between session and flow in networks

Tags: cisco, switch, router, network-core

What is the difference between **session** and **flow** in networks? In fact, I always visualize *flow* as a set of packets having the same source and destination. What confuses me is session. So I'd like to know the difference.

Thank you

Comment: This is a very broad question, and frankly I'm not sure what you're asking.  Please google "TCP/IP session" and if you have specific questions after doing some research maybe we can help.

Comment: I have elaborated the question furthur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **flow** is the data-plane stream of packets between sender and receiver that shares key IP header information.  For example, a client at 10.1.1.1 port 12398 communicating with a server at 192.168.1.1 port 22 for SSH is a specific flow that can be captured as the key fields don't change.

A **session** is the control-plane communication between sender and receiver.  The TCP 3-way handshake creates a session that establishes a connection between the sender's source port and receiver's destination listening port.  TCP window size, initial sequence and acknowledge values, and keepalives are negotiated as part of building the session.

Basically, **flow** represents the data-plane and **session** represents the control-plane.

**Edit:** Removed bidirectional requirement for a flow.

Comment: Flows can be unidirectional.

Answer (score 2):

To use an analogy, a flow is me speaking to you.  A session is a conversation between us.

Comment: A flow is me speaking to you --> Sounds like one direction flow right? 
A session is a conversation between us --> unidirectional flow, right?

Comment: A conversation implies a bidirectional flow -- I speak to you and you speak to me.

Answer (score 0):

A session typically involves a handshake and some back and forth communication whereas a flow may not involve a handshake and the communication may be uni-directional.  Think of a Web session vs a multicast flow.